# How to access resource mapped with @RequestMapping with @RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on the Spring Boot web application. I am running two different application one for service (Rest Resource) and other one is UI which show the request on HTML page on the bases of response got on the rest request.

My all rest services are created by

```
@Component
@Api(value = "/api/1/registration", description = "Access and manage your information")
@Path("/api/1/registration")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Slf4j
public class RegistrationResource {
...
...
@ApiOperation(value = "Find user by id", notes = "Return a user by id", response = Registration.class)
    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    @Timed
    @Override
    public Registration get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
// my logic 
   }
}
Restangular Request
  Restangular.one("registration/1").get().then(function (data) {
               ...
},function(error) {
...
});
```

When I do restangular request from ui, its working fine. Now I need to have a servlet resource. For that I create new resource class

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/1/test")
public class DownloadResource{

 @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadtesting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void download(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
  // I need to call this method... How can I 
 }
}
```

FYI: All my resources are registered as following...

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.sample.resource");
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> resources =
            reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class); //
    resources.forEach(r -> {
        log.debug("Registering resource " + r);
        register(beanFactory.getBean(r));
    });
```

// Same I did for RequestMapping.class also but I am getting  404 error for downloadtesting api.

NOTE: If I try with following version for downloadtesting in RegistrationResource then I am getting HttpServletRequest / Response null.

```
public class RegistrationResource{

 @Path("/downloadtesting")
 public void download(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
  // I need to call this method... How can I 
 }
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Do not forget that `@RestController` should only be used for data (Json...), if you want to use a controller for routing or as a servlet you need to use `@Controller`, not sure this solves your issue but fyi

Comment: @zakaria  as I know {@RestController} is a shorthand for {@Controller} and {@ResponseBody} . So to use {@Controller} instead of {@RestController} - does it make change the behavior?

Comment: It's pretty much the same.. but why are you using `@Path` instead of `@RequestMapping`, `@Path` is for JAX-RS not spring no? I think in your case it s only used by swagger to generate docs, and not by spring

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I think you have got my case. We are using JAX-RS with Jersey. And For all resources (Service API) I have used @Path. Now using jersey I need to implement downloadFile method, but I couldn't . Can you help me... FYI: When I use `@context` HttpServletResponse  - this is the instance of ShiroHttpServletResponse. Is it the issue ?

Comment: using Jersey in Spring boot ? I think you need to add `@Component` to your class, maybe a `@GET` as well, not sure if this provided by default.